# Create-react-app is installed with internal broken dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm learning react and have a problem with create-react-app util.
Once I've created a new project with create-react-app and typed "npm list --depth 0" - I got the following errors:

```html
PS C:\Users\dmitriiz\Documents\Sources\Sandbox\lovereact> npm list --depth 0
lovereact@0.1.0 C:\Users\dmitriiz\Documents\Sources\Sandbox\lovereact
+-- react@16.9.0
+-- react-dom@16.9.0
`-- react-scripts@3.1.1

npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@^5.0.0, required by @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@^5.0.0, required by @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.17.1
```

1) I create the app as: npx create-react-app lovereact (tried other ways - same result)

2) I don't install anything else (as you can see in the list above)

3) In my global list I have only npm package installed:

```html
C:\Users\dmitriiz\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- npm@6.11.3
```

4) My Node version is 10.14.1

5) I tried to install create-react-app globally and use the global instance, tried to install different packages to cure the errors, and some other things - nothing helps.

6) Maybe something wrong with create-react-app? For example this file:

```html
lovereact\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\eslint-plugin\package.json
```

has this eslint peer dep:

```html
"peerDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint": "^5.0.0"
  },
```

while the same time the lovereact\node_modules@typescript-eslint folder has not any eslint package inside. Ok maybe it should take the "eslint" package from the previous level at lovereact\node_modules\ ? 
Yes, create-react-app already has eslint package here and its version is 6.4.0

```html
"_id": "eslint@6.4.0",
```

that definitely should conform the "eslint": "^5.0.0" requirement, isn't it?

So please tell what's wrong with me or with create-react-app? I can't find exact the same problem on the Internet (including SO) but the same time I see that something wrong with create-react app default installation. Or maybe I miss something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should do `npm install` after `create-react-app`

Comment: Does this impede your development?  I don't see how this is a concern.  Everything works fine for me (just created new project to check).  I receive that message when running that command, but it doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: @KamilW, Tried to call npm install  in the project folder, it made some operations and printed the list of different warnings. Then I tried list --depth 0 again - same result, same those three errors

Comment: @ChrisG, I didn't yet but I only tried some simple guides and didn't use Typescript yet. Anyway even if it will not impede my dev process I don't like to see any errors right from the empty project init. I didn't find any "known problem" note about this on create-react-app documentation or anywhere else. 

So I just want to figure out what's going on and if it expected create-react-app behavior - then where's proofs for that? And if it's not expected then it worth to understand what causes the problem and fix it. That's why I'm concerned about it

Comment: @dzaraev There was PR merged in a couple of days ago that has not been pushed out.  This could resolve the issue you were seeing.  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/7540

Comment: @ChrisG, thanks it's interesting and possibly could help, but as I can see the latest release includes this commit already so if it would fix the problem it should got the fix since I used npx - if I rightly understand it fetches the latest version

Comment: I've posted the issue to the create-react-app repo on github and that's what they've answered:

"Yes we're aware of this issue. We've updated the dependencies that were causing these warnings. We'll be releasing shortly (hopefully in the next few hours)."

So if it will work after new release I'll close the issue here with release version number

Comment: updated to 3.1.2 but still got this (third) ERR:
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.17.1

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve that problem by performing the following steps:

1.- Delete the package-lock.json file in addition to node_modules

2.- Install version 6.4.0 of esLint with the command:

```
npm i eslint@6.4.0
```

3.- Install all the modules to use set in package.json through the command:

```
npm i
```

4.- Finally create an .env file and add the following command, as follows:

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Update node version , there is node v12.**  then in the directory you want to install your app , use the following code :

```
npx create-react-app yourAppName
```